# External URL Link extremely low

Tags: custom-button, account

I have currently implemented a button on the account page with a formula that opens a URL based on an external customer ID (Magento). Functionality works great but when I use the button the new window opens and the page takes around 12 seconds to load. Wondering the cause of this and anything that can be done?

Comment: How you are taking measure of the load time? Is it constant every time?

Comment: Just manually, pretty much the same every time but the issue is more that just for opening a link that is quite a long time.

Comment: Generally it would be issue with the internet speed.

Comment: But no such issue is occurring with other pages. The salesforce redirect is being shown for the extended period then the intended page is loading immediately.

Comment: Spends a long time on this URL: https://cs108.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.Integration?scontrolCaching= ...